# Why can't I upload images to Parse? Anybody know of a different way to do this?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I just need to upload some images, and I feel like my simple code should work, but for some reason it isn't. I'm getting an error saying that my object exceeds the Parse.com limit of 128kb... And I'm sure it doesn't actually exceed that. Code is here.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func addCards(urlString:String) {

            var newCard = PFObject(className: "Cards")

            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

            let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                response, data, error in

                newCard["image"] = data             

                newCard.save()

            })

    }

addCards("http://image.com/image")
```

Comment: Does the data file need to be cast as a PFFile?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't just be pushing the image data direct into the object. Instead, create a `PFFile` instance with the data and set that. Then, save the file and the card at the same time (using `saveAll`).

Answer (score 0):

See the following link from Parse documentations which has a code snippet and also the reason for using PFFile as suggested by Wain:

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#files

According to Parse documentation: You can easily store images by converting them to NSData and then using PFFile. Suppose you have a UIImage named image that you want to save as a PFFile:

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.png", data:imageData)

var userPhoto = PFObject(className:"UserPhoto")
userPhoto["imageName"] = "My trip to Hawaii!"
userPhoto["imageFile"] = imageFile
userPhoto.saveInBackground()
```